# Use Links as LIstItem in Wicket ListView

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, wicket

I'm trying to define a link as a ListItem of a Wicket ListView as below:

```
<div wicket:id="outer" class="list-group">
    <a wicket:id="list_items" class="list-group-item">
        <span wicket:id="name"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

There shouldn't be any div/span around each item. The expected output is:

```
<div class="list-group">
    <a class="list-group-item" href="./foo/bar1">
        <span>bar1</span>
    </a>
    <a class="list-group-item" href="./foo/bar2">
        <span>bar2</span>
    </a>
    <a class="list-group-item" href="./foo/bar3">
        <span>bar3</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

This can be achieved by setting the `href` manually:

```
@Override
protected void populateItem(final ListItem<Course> item)
{
    String url=urlFor(FooPage.class,new PageParameters().add("name",item.getModelObject().getBar())).toString();
    item.add(new AttributeModifier("href",url));
    item.add(new Label("name", new PropertyModel(item.getModel(), "bar")));
}
```

Everything is fine and I will continue with this solution, but it somehow feels wrong. Is this the best way to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tekki's answer is perfectly fine, but here's another trick:

```
new RepeatingView("list_items") {
    protected void onPopulate() {
        removeAll();

        for (Course course : list) {
            PageParameters parameters = new PageParameters().add("name", course.getBar());
            BookmarkablePageLink<Object> link = new BookmarkablePageLink<>(newChildId(), FooPage.class, parameters);
            add(link);

            link.add(new Label("name", course.getBar()));    
        }
    }
}
```

So essentially we're skipping creating of intermediary item components, and use the links directly as children of the repeater.

Comment: Getting rid of one wicket id is pretty nice.

Answer (score 2):

It indeed feels a bit wrong to use the AttributeModifier to modify the href-attribute.

If you don't want to have any actual HTML-tag arround each list element in your resulting HTML, you could use the `<wicket:container>` tag. It is not rendered into the final page, unless you are in running development mode.

So your HTML could look like this

```
<div class="list-group">
    <wicket:container wicket:id="outer">
        <a wicket:id="link" class="list-group-item">
            <span wicket:id="name"></span>
        </a>
    </wicket:container>
</div>
```

and your Java code like this

```
add(new ListView<Course>("list-group", list) {
    @Override
    protected void populateItem(ListItem<Course> item) {
        PageParameters parameters = new PageParameters().add("name", item.getModelObject().getBar());
        BookmarkablePageLink<Object> link = new BookmarkablePageLink<>("link", FooPage.class, parameters);
        item.add(link);
        link.add(new Label("name", new PropertyModel(item.getModel(), "bar")));
    }
});
```

Alternatively instead of using the `<wicket:container>` tag you could also use standard `<div>` tags and set `item.setRenderBodyOnly(true)` in `ListView#populateItem()` to hide them, but I think that is slightly less elegant.